# Pandas min values of timeseries filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pandas newcomer, and I'm trying to solve the next problem.

I have a dataset (originally it is around 2 mil rows)

```
test = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date' : ['2020-04-01','2020-04-02','2020-04-03',
                         '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06',
                         '2020-04-01','2020-04-02','2020-04-03'],
                  'Set' : ['Set1','Set1','Set1','Set1','Set1','Set1',
                         'Set2','Set2','Set2'],
                  'Type': ['Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1',
                         'Type1','Type1','Type1'],
                  'Category': ['Category1','Category1','Category1','Category1','Category1','Category1',
                         'Category2','Category2','Category2'],
                  'Rooms' : [6,5,4,7,2,9,3,5,1]
            })
```

I need create a new column that will contain a list of 21 values in each row.

Each values of the list corresponds to min number of Rooms in next 1 to 20 days for every (Set - Type - Category - Date) combination.

For example first row contains [2020-04-01, Set1, Type1, Category1, 6]
I need to look through entire df find all rows containing same [Set1, Type1, Category1], inside this filtered part I need to find min value of rooms for:
2020-04-01 + 0 days, 2020-04-01 + 1 days , 2020-04-01 + 2 days ... 2020-04-01 + 20 days.

I came up with this code, and it works but only on a small chunk of the df. When i try to run on entire df it takes infinite amount of time.  I'm sure it can be optimized, probably with groupby, but I still cant get how to use it properly.

```
for i in range(len(test)):  #iterate through entire dataframe
    x=[]                    #create a list that will be added to the new column at the end
    current_set = test.loc[    #filter out needed part of the dataframe
            (test.Set== test.Set.loc[i]) &
            (test.Type == test.Type.loc[i]) &
            (test.Category == test.Category.loc[i]) &
            (test.Date >= test.loc[i,'Date']) &
            (test.Date <= test.loc[i,'Date']+pd.Timedelta(days=20))
            ]
    for n in range(1,22):         #run internal loop to fill out the x list by additionally filtering 
        if len(current_set)>=n:  #check if there is enough days after current date
            c_date = test.Date < test.Date.loc[i]+pd.Timedelta(days=n) #if True filter current_set to needed state
            x.append(min(current_room.loc[c_date,'Rooms']))
        else:
            x.append(0)

    test.at[i,'Min_Rooms']=x #add generated list to new column
```

The whole code to run from a single cell

```
test = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date' : ['2020-04-01','2020-04-02','2020-04-03',
                         '2020-04-04','2020-04-05','2020-04-06',
                         '2020-04-01','2020-04-02','2020-04-03'],
                  'Set' : ['Set1','Set1','Set1','Set1','Set1','Set1',
                         'Set2','Set2','Set2'],
                  'Type': ['Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1',
                         'Type1','Type1','Type1'],
                  'Category': ['Category1','Category1','Category1','Category1','Category1','Category1',
                         'Category2','Category2','Category2'],
                  'Rooms' : [6,5,4,7,2,9,3,5,1]
            })

# Convert 'Date' to daetime
test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'], format= '%Y/%m/%d')

# Create new column
test.at[0,'Min_Rooms'] = 1

#Convert to object type in order to insert lists
test['Min_Rooms'] = test['Min_Rooms'].astype(object)

# Start the loop
for i in range(len(test)):
    x=[]
    current_room = test.loc[
            (test.Set == test.Set.loc[i]) &
            (test.Type == test.Type.loc[i]) &
            (test.Category == test.Category.loc[i]) &
            (test.Date >= test.loc[i,'Date']) &
            (test.Date <= test.loc[i,'Date']+pd.Timedelta(days=20))
            ]
    for n in range(1,22):
        if len(current_room)>=n:
            c_date = test.Date < test.Date.loc[i]+pd.Timedelta(days=n)
            x.append(min(current_room.loc[c_date,'Rooms']))
        else:
            x.append(0)

    test.at[i,'Min_Rooms']=x

print(test.to_markdown())
```

I have decreased number of days from 21 to 7, and here is my result.
As you can see in the first row every value in the Min_Rooms list is the minimum of Rooms for the same Set+Type+Category combination for 2020-04-01 +0 days, +1 day .. +6 days. So 7 days in total including initial date itself.
But since there is only 6 day available in dataframe for (Set1  | Type1  | Category1), from 01/APR to 05/APR, the last value in the list is 0.
For the second row the values starts from 02/APR, and since from this date only 5 days are in the df , the last two values are 0, and so on.

```
|    | Dat        | Set   | Type   | Category   |   Rooms | Min_Rooms             |
|---:|:-----------|:------|:-------|:-----------|--------:|:----------------------|
|  0 | 2020-04-01 | Set1  | Type1  | Category1  |       6 | [6, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0] |
|  1 | 2020-04-02 | Set1  | Type1  | Category1  |       5 | [5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0] |
|  2 | 2020-04-03 | Set1  | Type1  | Category1  |       4 | [4, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0] |
|  3 | 2020-04-04 | Set1  | Type1  | Category1  |       7 | [7, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|  4 | 2020-04-05 | Set1  | Type1  | Category1  |       2 | [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|  5 | 2020-04-06 | Set1  | Type1  | Category1  |       9 | [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|  6 | 2020-04-01 | Set2  | Type1  | Category2  |       3 | [3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|  7 | 2020-04-02 | Set2  | Type1  | Category2  |       5 | [5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|  8 | 2020-04-03 | Set2  | Type1  | Category2  |       1 | [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
```

Comment: can you add the expected output? your solutuon doesn't work for me I get a type error. just  2-3 rows will do i think i get your gist from your explanation.

Comment: I added  the entire code to run from a single cell, should work

Comment: In your sample data, you only have one record per day-category-type-set combination. Is the real data the same? If not, you may want to enrich your sample data.

Comment: Roy2012, yes , it is. Initially every row in dataframe is saying how many rooms are available in this particular Hotel(Set), of particular Room Type and Room Category for this particular Date. So every row is unique. Every Hotel(Set) can have different number of Room Types and Categories in different combinations. Some Room types and Categories can be unique to only one Hotel, others can be of common use. My actual goal is to find the maximum available number of rooms (Type + Category combination) in every hotel, for every arrival date, for stay duration from 1 to 21 days.

Comment: For example if in Hotel X, 01-01-2020 we have 5 rooms of Type1+Category1, the next day 02-01-2020 - 3 Rooms, and 03-02-2020 - 8 Rooms. This means that for those who will come to the hotel at 01-01-2020, and wants to stay in the room of Type1+Category1 till 03-02-2020,  we still have only 3 rooms available. This is why I'm searching for min value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what you're looking for.

- I'm using `rolling` to create a list of available rooms for the past N days, and then using `shift' to shift it backward so that each date will look at future availability.
- For the sake of example, I'm using NUM_DAYS = 7. I've also broken it into several steps for clarity.
- To calculate available rooms for future dates, the first thing I do is add dummy dates with zero availability to the dataframe. I'm removing these dummy dates in the end.

```
    NUM_DAYS = 7
    
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
    
    #New records is a set of future dummy dates with 0 availability. 
    new_records = df.reset_index().groupby(["Set", "Type", "Category"], as_index = False)["Date"].max()
    
    new_records["Date"] = new_records.Date.apply(lambda d: pd.date_range(d + datetime.timedelta(days = 1), 
                                                                         periods=NUM_DAYS, freq="1D"))
    new_records = new_records.explode("Date")
    new_records["dummy"] = True
    new_records["Rooms"] = 0
    
    # expand the data to include these dummy dates. 
    df = pd.concat([df, new_records], axis=0)
    
    # calculate the minimum availability on any given date. 
    df["min_per_day"] = df.groupby(["Set", "Type", "Category", "Date"])["Rooms"].transform(min)
    
    df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
        
    list_of_lists=[]
    def add_to_lists(s):
        list_of_lists.append(list(s))
        return 0
        
    # Build rolling lists of N days. Since 'rolling' can't work with 
    # lists, use 'list_of_lists' to maintain the results, and then add 
    # them as a new column. 
    df.groupby(["Set", "Type", "Category"]).rolling(str(NUM_DAYS) + "D", 
                                                    min_period = 1)["min_per_day"].apply(add_to_lists, raw=True)
    df.sort_values(["Set", "Type", "Category"], inplace = True)
    df["past_mins"] = list_of_lists
    
    # Shift the results by N days - now, every date looks at the 
    # future rather than at the past. 
    df["future_mins"] = df.groupby(["Set", "Type", "Category"])["past_mins"].shift((-(NUM_DAYS-1)))
    
    # Drop dummy dates and irrelevant data. 
    df = df[df.dummy.isna()]
    df.drop(["dummy", "min_per_day", "past_mins"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
             Set   Type   Category  Rooms                          future_mins
Date                                                                          
2020-04-01  Set1  Type1  Category1      6  [6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0]
2020-04-02  Set1  Type1  Category1      5  [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-03  Set1  Type1  Category1      4  [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-04  Set1  Type1  Category1      3  [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-05  Set1  Type1  Category1      2  [2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-06  Set1  Type1  Category1      1  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-01  Set2  Type1  Category2      3  [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-02  Set2  Type1  Category2      2  [2.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2020-04-03  Set2  Type1  Category2      1  [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! To be honest , I'm struggling to understand how your magic works. I added my desired output with decreased future days from 21 to 7

Comment: I also changed the Rooms values to be more iconic

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope it helps (and feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it does).

Comment: Did this answer your question?